# Android ADB connect empty host name

Tags: android, adb, hostname

I use ADB over WiFi to connect to an Android device. When I type

```
adb connect <device ip>
```

I get error

```
empty hostname
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For me, simply restarting adb solved the problem

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `net.hostname` property on your device. The easiest way is to use the `setprop` command via a root shell on the device.

```
setprop net.hostname TypeAnyHostName
```

If this is not working for you, see [other solutions here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-do-i-change-the-name-of-my-android-device). This is a temporary solution, the problem repeats again some time later.